# Connect to Website via Cookie (setRequestProperty)

Tags: java, php, cookies

I want to write a Java Application, which logs into a website and then navigates through different sites through a cookie authentication. 
I have managed it to log into the website and retrieve it's code. 
First Problem:

While looping through the HeaderFieldKeys there is no "Set-Cookie" Key, there are only: Date, Server, X-Powered-By, Expires, Last-Modified, Cache-Control, Cache-Control, Pragma, X-UA-Compatible, X-Frame-Options, Strict-Transport-Security, Vary, Connection, Transfer-Encoding and Content-Type.

As you can see in my code I tried another code to retrieve the cookies, which worked. Now with the cookies I want to navigate to another link of the website, but it won't work.

```
package myEDKS;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

public class SpielHelfer 
{
    public static HttpCookie cookieW; 
    public static String cookieV;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            // Instantiate CookieManager;
            // make sure to set CookiePolicy
            CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
            manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

            // get content from URLConnection;
            // cookies are set by web site
            URL url = new URL("https://www.w-da.net/wws/109580.php?sid=41853050108060779043427902790460");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();


         // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            // send your parameters to your site
            ps.print("login_login=********");
            ps.print("&login_password=********");

            // we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
            con.getInputStream();

            // get cookies from underlying
            // CookieStore
            CookieStore cookieJar =  manager.getCookieStore();
            List <HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
            for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) 
            {
              System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: " + cookie);
              cookieW = cookie;
              String cookieC = cookie.getValue();
              int x = cookieC.length();
              cookieV = cookieC;
              System.out.println("**************************************");
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to get cookie using CookieHandler");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(cookieW);

        try 
        {
            URL url2 = new URL("https://www.w-da.net/wws/109580.php?sid=41853050108060779043427902790460");
            URLConnection con2 = url2.openConnection();
            con2.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieV);
            con2.connect();
            BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con2.getInputStream()));
            String line2 = null;
            while ((line2 = in2.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(line2);
            }
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to set cookie using CookieHandler");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I not good in Java, but I recommend try to use Selenium Webdriver. Because it help you navigate on websites in more higher way. It contain nice API with all needed you function. Because write it in this way will be very long and hard.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Yes I have read about that but for reasons of flexibility and personal knowledge I would prefer to write the code on my own.